# Block access to port from within a java application

Tags: java, networking

I developed a java application that connects to a certain service (running on same host).  This is a test setup.  I want to test behavior when the application is not able to connect to the service.  Is there a way when I start my app, I can call some API to block access to a certain port.  That way down the line when my app tries to create a connection to the app, the createConnection fails.
(I know I can use iptables to block the port, which will need sudo access.  But I want to block to that specific port for my specific app only).

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: You could create an integration test and 'mock' the response from your service - the response would 'mock' different response codes and even a failed connection (if you wished)

Comment: You can use mocking framework like wiremock and mock the responses. When you are running the application in the test mode change the endpoint so that application hits wiremock. Keep service url configurable in the application.